# Why does the following code run out of memory?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, out-of-memory

The following code describes 2 harmonic oscillators. They are initially uncoupled and independent and am only looking at one of them, which is a mechanical oscillator. The other oscillator's variables have been declared and forced to 0. I first do 300,000 time iterations and do this for 80 different frequencies of wdm (mechanical drive w).

```
//find frequency response
int index_A;
double wdm_1;
wdm_1=wm-2*3.142*2e5;
double wdm_2;
wdm_2=wm+2*3.142*2e5;
double wdm_prec=2*3.142*5e3;
index_A=(wdm_2-wdm_1)/wdm_prec;
printf("%d \n", index_A);
```

[However, my code runs till 58 frequencies and gives this error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5a6F.jpg)

**Strangely, if I run the code in 2 parts of 40 frequencies each and append the files together, it works fine.**

[Resonance peak in frequency domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tT8n.jpg)

**Also, when I reduce the size of v0 to 3, the code works properly**. However, I will need the other variables later.

```
int j=0;
    for (j=0; j<= index_A ; j++){
        wdm=wdm_1+j*wdm_prec;
        printf("%d \n",j);
        v0[0] = 0;
        v0[1] = 0;
        v0[2] = 0;
        v0[3] = 0;
        v0[4] = 0;
        v0[5] = 0;
        v0[6]= wdm;

            for (i=0; i< n ; i++){
                if (cabs(xa)>=1){
                        printf("Breaking Loop \n");
                        break;
                        }

                v1 = rk4vec_ameya_complex_1 ( tau, 7, v0, dtau, rk4vec_f_ameya_complex_1 );
                memcpy(v0, v1, 4 * sizeof ( double complex ) );
                tau=tau+dtau;
            }

        fprintf(f1, "%g, %g \n", wdm/(2*3.142), cabs(v1[2]) );
    }
printf("Completed");
fclose(f1);
```

At the end of time iterations, I save the value of the frequency wdm and last value of displacement x=v1[2] in a file and move on to do time iterations with another frequency. Hence, my file contains the frequency response.

```
fprintf(f1, "%g, %g \n", wdm/(2*3.142), cabs(v1[2]) );
```

I have used runge kutta (rk4.c) from people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/rk4/rk4.html and modified it for complex datatype using

```
#include <complex.h>
```

Following is the function runge-kutta-4 has to solve:

```
/******************************************************************************/

double complex *rk4vec_f_ameya_complex_1 ( double t, int n, double complex u[] )

/******************************************************************************/

{
    double complex drive_m;
    double complex drive_c;
    double x;
    double xrf0_1;
    double complex *uprime;
    uprime = ( double * ) malloc ( 7 * sizeof ( double complex ) );

    //Check if memory unavailable
    if(uprime==NULL){
        printf("No memory available \n");
        return 0;
    }

    ///////////////////Second Order////////////////////////
    xrf0_1=xrf0*(1-exp(-0.2*t));
    drive_m=(xrf0*cexp(I*((u[6]-wm)/gammac)*t)/(2*wm*gammac));
    uprime[2]=u[3];
    uprime[3]=(wm/gammac)*(drive_m-u[3]*(2*I+2*gammam/wm)-u[2]*(2*I*gammam/gammac));

    return uprime;
    free(uprime);
}
```

Kindly suggest any solutions if my usage of malloc() is responsible for running out of memory.

Comment: You need to cut your example down to the relevant code and show it as functions, not anonymous blocks that we have no idea how they relate.  Remove everything you have commented out and focus just on where the code is giving you problems.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I reduced the code

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem - you free `uprime` after you have returned from `rk4vec_f_ameya_complex_1`, I'd expect you to be getting an unreachable code warning. Also as `uprime` is always the same size why do you use `malloc` at all? If you just make it an array of size 7 then you won't have issues with malloc and your code will probably run faster.

Comment: Is it necessary to free uprime at all?

Comment: @Ameya, as it stands each time the function rk4vec_f_ameya_complex_1 is called it mallocs a new array of complex numbers, unless you free these at the end of function you have a memory leak. There is no automatic tidy-up of memory allocated by malloc.

Comment: I declared uprime as a static array as per http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_return_arrays_from_function.htm. Still stops at 58 iterations.